# Page by page 'engagement' in Google Analytics

Tags: time, report, duration

One report I like to use is the 'Engagement' report. I would like to apply this metric on a page by page basis. For example, I want to find out more than the average time on a page, I want to look at spread of times (duration) for specific pages. Can this be achieved in Google Analytics? I have hd a look at secondary dimensions and custom reports but can't see a way to achieve this.

Comment: Are you using the Android/iOS SDK or the web version?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for the web framework, but with either the Android or iOS SDKs, you can view the spread of times (duration) or any other histogram by using [Events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/events) that have a category, action, or label that is a predefined bin. For example, you could name the bins something like "time00001", "time00002", etc and then call something like this in your code:

```
sendEvent("EngagementReport", "duration", "time00001", 1);
```

Then,

1. click on Engagement > Events > Overview.
2. At the bottom of the page, click on the 'view full report' link under the 'Event label' section.
3. Click on the bubble icon in the upper-right-hand corner.
4. Click on the bars icon in the upper-right-hand corner (but slightly lower-left of the bubbles icon)
5. Order the x-axis alphabetically and you should be able to see the bins "time00001", "time00002", etc sorted in such a way that you can see the histogram of the duration of time on each page.

I'm not sure how to do this in the web analytics, but I'm pretty sure it isn't too difficult. Here's what the result looks like for me:

[image]